# How to create thin invisible margin around picture and paragraph using HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML, and I'm applying the following code to get my picture to sit beside my text:

```
 <div id='container'>
      <img src='someimage.jpg' style='float: left;'/>
      <p>some text (that will now wrap around the image</p>
 </div>
```

How can I create a small 1/8 or 1/16" of an inch margin between the paragraph and the text? Right now, the text is too close to the picture, almost touching.

Answer (score 0):

in css write this

img
{
     margin-right : 0.5px;   //you can have any amount of margin in px/em/ etc
}

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#container p{
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

or

```
#container img{
    margin-right:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First to wrap around image I personally use `align: left;` as for the margin if you are not using an embedded or external CSS file (which is bad practice but fine for new learners) then you can add it using `<img src='someimage.jpg' style='float: left; margin-right: 5px;">`

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='someimage.jpg' style='float: left;margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:10px'/>
```